# Avoid writing Error messages if level="info" in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I want to maintain separate log files for info logs and error logs. However I dont want error logs to be written to the info log file i.e when level="info", i dont want error logs to be written to file.

```
<RollingFile name="Filer"  fileName="logs/info.log"
        filePattern="logs/info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${SIZE}" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>

<RollingFile name="App"  fileName="logs/error.log"
        filePattern="logs/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${SIZE}" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>
<Loggers>       
    <Logger name="org.pro" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="File" level="info" />
        <AppenderRef ref="App" level="error" />
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
<Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
</Root>
```

Although I am able to generate different log files. error.log file is generated correctly having only error logs. But info.log contains both info and error logs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate both `<Loggers>` .

Like this :

```
<Loggers>       
    <Logger name="org.pro" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Filer" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="org.pro" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="App" />
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Above will log INFO in `logs/info.log` file and ERROR in `logs/error.log` file.

Comment: Thanks. but this way info.log still generates both info and error logs..and  error.log generated is empty.

Comment: So if any ERROR level logs are not there so it is empty. Both will be generated. If you do not want any of them remove RollingFile

Comment: The issue is that when we have level="info" , log4j2 ingests all the messages including info, debug, error into the file. Here I do NOT want error messages to go to the log file.

Comment: With above code info.log should only have INFO messages. Please check once the contain of generated file.

Comment: This solved the issue `<Filters>
    <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
   </Filters>`